# Wrong year set when converting NSDate to NSString

Tags: string, date, nsdate

I'm trying to produce a string using a NSDate category in this way:

```
NSString* dateString = nil;
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocal currentLocale]];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd LLL YYYY"];
dateString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:self];
return dateString;
```

The conversion works fine except in ONE case (I report the debug session): 
if I try to convert an NSDate object like this:

```
(gdb) po self
2012-01-01 00:00:00 +0000
```

I obtain:

```
(gdb) po dateString
01 Jan 2011
```

Why the year is set back to 2011????

PS. I have already checked [NSDate returns wrong year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942005/nsdate-returns-wrong-year) and I'm NOT using the Japanese calendar.

thanks a lot

Comment: You need to change `NSLocal` to `NSLocale`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
     NSDate *pickerDate = [NSDate date];
     NSCalendar*       calendar = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
     NSDateComponents* components = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
        components.day = 0; //This value to take from today to next 1 or 2 or 3 days
        NSDate* newDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents: components toDate: pickerDate options: 0];
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMMM"];
        NSString *textDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:newDate]];
        [dateFormatter release];
```

Comment: Actually I may have found a simpler solution..in the date format replace YYYY with yyyy
Can you confirm it works for you too?

Comment: Yes this is the universal date format for all date elements:  setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd' 'HH':'mm':'ss'-> MM month mm minutes yyyy year and so on :)

Comment: Because YYYY is not UDF for Years, you must use yyyy.